# EOF Flex Calculator

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, eof

I am writing a simple calculator in Flex/Bison and I keep getting an EOF error when I try and compile my flex code. Can anyone tell me why or how to fix it? Thanks!

```
%{
#define YYSTYPE double
#include "calc.tab.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
%}

white [ \t]+
digit [0-9]
integer {digit}+
exponent [eE][+-]?{integer}
real {integer}("."{integer})?{exponent}?

%%

{white} { }
{real} { yylval=atof(yytext); 
 return NUMBER;
}

"+" return PLUS;
"-" return MINUS;
"*" return TIMES;
"/" return DIVIDE;
"^" return POWER;
"(" return LEFT;
")" return RIGHT;
"\n" return END;
```

Comment: What is the precise error message, and at what point does it appear?

Comment: You should include standard headers before your own, not after.

Answer (score 1):

your header is incorrectn, it should be like this

```
%{ 
   #include <stdlib.h>   
   #include "calc.tab.h"
   #define YYSTYPE double 
%}
```